# How can i fix this problem when i call cartItems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Ive been trying to fix my JS code for an E-Commerce site for a long time and nothing seems to be working, I've tried putting it in other ways and I've done quite a-lot of research in the past few weeks. If someone could help it would be very much appreciated. I cant seem to get it working so please someone help!!!

Heres my code

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FaBars } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
function Header() {

const {cartItems} = useSelector(state=> state.cartReducer)
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
            Minis Services
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
            aria-controls="navbarNav"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon">
              <FaBars size={25} color="white" />
            </span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">
                  User
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                  Software
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                  Logout
                </Link>
              </li>

              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                  Cart {cartItems.length}
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Heres my app.js file

```
import "./App.css";
import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage";
import CartPage from "./pages/CartPage";
import Productinfo from "./pages/Productinfo";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import "./stylesheets/products.css";
import "./stylesheets/layout.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="/login" exact element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/register" exact element={<RegisterPage />} />
            <Route
              path="/productinfo/:productid"
              exact
              element={<Productinfo />}
            />
            <Route path="/cart" exact element={<CartPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and heres my store.js file

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({})


export const initialStore = {
    cartReducer : {
        cartItems : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`cartItems`)) ?? []
    }
}

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialStore,
    composeEnhancers()
);
```

Heres my console error

[image: IMG]

Comment: "this problem" ... "can't get it working" .... my guess is, you'll need to "debug the problem" to get it to "work"

Comment: Oh, just saw the image of the error (you should really have the error as text in the question) ... the issue us that `useSelector(state=> state.cartReducer)` doesn't return an Object with a property called `cartItems`

Comment: Start from the top: Read the first error message thoroughly. It has nothing to do with the code you showed us. Fix that issue first. Then see if the other issues are resolved as well or not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=unexpected+key+reducer+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: Somewhere you wrote cartreducer instead of cartReducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems OK but you forgot to add store to Redux Provider

checkout this code for app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage";
import CartPage from "./pages/CartPage";
import Productinfo from "./pages/Productinfo";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage";
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import "./stylesheets/products.css";
import "./stylesheets/layout.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {store} from "/path/of/store.js/file";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Homepage />} />
            <Route path="/login" exact element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/register" exact element={<RegisterPage />} />
            <Route
              path="/productinfo/:productid"
              exact
              element={<Productinfo />}
            />
            <Route path="/cart" exact element={<CartPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Set the path of store.js in app.js and then, I think it must work.

Comment: ive just added the new code. take a look when u can :)

Comment: @sylo checkout this answer